# Pandas: retain n% of data for unique values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of unique products and reviews:

```
ProductID  Comment
  1        Great product!
  2        Terrible
  2        Amazing!
```

The table (a csv) is about ~170,000 rows. I'm looking to retain 5% of comments for each unique ProductID. Is there a functionality in Pandas that will let me do this?

Comment: `Is there a functionality in Pandas that will let me do this?` - yes.

Comment: Does [Pandas - Group by one column and aggregate other column to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093644/pandas-group-by-one-column-and-aggregate-other-column-to-list) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use groupby with sample.

```
df.groupby('ProductID').sample(frac=.05)
```